# Rails best_in_place gem not updating data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, best-in-place

I've looked everywhere for a solution to this, but all of the common solutions to this issue aren't working for me.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

My problem is just that the rails best_in_place gem doesn't save any of my data after I make a change.  It will allow me to type in the new change, but it won't update the database after I press enter (it also doesn't work if I refresh the page, which was the initial problem on the RailsCast for this gem).

**Controller code:**

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @renter.update_attributes(renter_params)
    format.json { render json: @renter }
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to @renter
  else

    render 'edit'
  end

end
```

end

**View page code**

```
    <li><span class="content"><b>Name: </b><%= best_in_place @renter, :name %></span></li>
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit: Adding renter_params from controller**

```
def renter_params
    params.require(:renter).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

(Note: I've never had any problems with renter_params per se, my updates always save OK in the database)

**Edit: adding code from javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require best_in_place
//= require best_in_place.purr
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.purr
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**renters.js.coffee**

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
jQuery ->
    $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

Comment: What is renter_params here? Also @renter is unlikely to contain anything until you set it. See the examples on https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place

Comment: Last commit was a year ago, and it has 148 issues, probably it's not working with rails 4.

Comment: `best_in_place` gem is working fine with my Rails 4. is your update action working without best_in_place?

Comment: also, if you require login to perform updates, it won't let you update if you haven't logged in.

Comment: thanks for the quick replies :) Added renter_params in for more context.

Wali - I thought that too, but I'm only editing on my current logged in user.
Dsatch - sorry I didn't give full context, but @renter is initialized like so:       `@renter=Renter.find(params[:id])` ... That's elsewhere in the code because it's before-filtered, but it is initialized to the correct user

Comment: can you try adding `:type => :input` option. Like this: `<%= best_in_place @renter, :name, :type => :input %>`. It should normally make no difference, and default to input type but just in case, try it

Comment: by the way, when replying to comments, if you want the users to be notified, tag us as in so @dsatch .

Comment: Also, can you try it without `<li><span class="content"><b>Name:`. maybe the html is hindering the gem's effort. I compared your solution to mine (Rails 4) and I don't see any difference.

Comment: @WaliAli thanks for that tip on the replies.  I followed another solution on here prior to posting and added the :type => :input piece, but with no difference.

I tried removing the HTML as well, but to no avail

Comment: @dsatch  (bumping with an "@" since I didn't do that in my prior response to you both)

Comment: update your question with code in `javascripts/application.js` and the `best_in_place` code in your coffeescript

Comment: @WaliAli app JS uploaded along with coffeescript file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you haven't yet, modify your gem as this:

```
gem 'best_in_place', github: 'bernat/best_in_place'
```

by simply doing `gem 'best_in_place'` didn't work for me.

if that doesn't work, as the [documentation](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) suggest, replace:

```
format.json { render json: @renter }
```

with:

```
format.json { respond_with_bip(@renter) }
```

`respond_with_bip` is a "utility method you should use in your controller in order to provide the response that is expected by the javascript side, using the :json format", says the documentation. I'm not sure how much this matters as my Rails 4 app is working without it.

Finally, if the `update` action is restricted to logged in users only, make sure you are logged in.